# How to access $wp_query object from array of posts given by get_posts?

Tags: wp-query, loop, get-posts

I have a simple custom query driven by `get_posts`:

```
<ul>
<?php 
$args = array('post_type' => 'event', 'numberposts' => 6 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); 
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
</ul>
```

However, there's a need to access this custom loop's query object - the one which is accessible by default if you do custom loops using `new WP_Query` method. (This is needed to get connected posts of other CPTs, mechanism driven by the excellent [Posts2Posts](https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki/each_connected) plugin's `each_connected`.) Is it possible to get to the query object from `get_posts`? Or the only way to do this is to remake the loop in the `new WP_Query` style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter any WP query using  [`pre_get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts). The (sometimes) tricky part is that it is run against all queries of WP so you need to pinpoint your query using WP conditionals (`is_admin()`, `is_page()`, `is_archive()`, etc... ).

You'll find a few useful examples on that page, too.

Comment: Ah, good point, I suppose if one did eg `if ( ! $query->is_main_query() && $query->get( 'post_type' ) == 'event' && $query->get( 'numberposts' ) == 6 ) {` one would be almost sure to isolate the query.

Comment: That's it, thanks. We setup `pre_get_posts` in functions.php and then are able to change the appropriate query parameters such as `connected_type` and `connected_items`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

<del>Yes, I think the only way is</del> (See 
Andrei Gheorghiu's answer) If you choose to remake the loop, the slightly tricky bit is to make the `$args` array the same as `get_posts()`'s defaults:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'event', 'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'post_status' => 'publish', // If post_type 'attachment' then 'post_status' => 'inherit'
    'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC',
    'suppress_filters' => true,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true, 'no_found_rows' => true,
);
$query = new WP_Query;
$myposts = $query->query( $args );
```